# Настройка sudoers

Tags: linux, sudo

Как разрешить пользователю доступ к папке вместе со всеми её подпапками (рекурсивно) средствами `sudo`?

Пример:
Есть `Cmnd_Alias ADMBCP = /opt/aaa/bbb/*, /opt/aaa/bbb/ccc/*, /opt/aaa/bbb/ddd/*`

Хотелось бы `Cmnd_Alias ADMBCP = /opt/aaa/*` чтобы пользователь через судо мог запустить любой скрыпт в директории и во всех вложеных поддиректориях.

P.S. Политика `sudo` запретить всё, кроме четкообозначенных действий. Приложение установлено под root пользователем, но есть необходимость запускать бинаркини из директории приложения. Указывать все возможные пути это долго и очень нудно.
Есть бинарник по адресу: `/opt/web/bin/test` и `/opt/web/bin64/test64`, как одной строкой в sudo разрешить доступ к двум бинарникам?

Полномочия на директорию `/opt/web/` - `drwxr-xr---`, владелец `root:root`

Права на директорию `/opt` тут не важны, но всё же - `drwxr-xr-x.`

Comment: Если у пользователя есть доступ к `sudo`, никакие дополнительные права ему уже не нужны. Уточните, пожалуйста, вопрос.

Comment: а какие права стоят на папке `/opt` ? У меня Qt установлено в `/opt/Qt`, прекрасно запускается все из под пользователя.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ найден - на сайте sudo огромный шрифтом написано - `*` не работает на вложенные директории...

Comment: Т.е. значит на файлы работает?

Comment: Да, на все вложенные файлы работает без проблем.

Answer (score 1):

1-й вариант:

```
sudo chmod -R /opt/web a+r
```

Но это откроет доступ для чтения /opt/web для всех пользователей.

2-й вариант
в файле `/etc/sudoers`
прописать строчку:

```
username ALL = /path/to/needed/script, /path/to/another/script
```

Вместо ALL можно прописать hostname машины. Сам не пробовал, вычитал в `man sudoers`

Comment: Открывать всем доступ вообще не вариант. Второй способ мне известен, но когда у тебя всего 2 бинарника или 10 это не проблема, а если из 100?! Потому-то и возник вопрос. В Офф манах я не нашел ответа на вопрос.

Comment: а `username ALL = /path/to/your/scripts/` не сработает? Если 100 бинарников в 100 разных папках, то это, похоже, тупик. Тут только пользователю давать права `sudo`

Comment: На одну директорию к бинарнику сработает без проблем, а вот если в директории scripts будет вложенная директория с бинарниками, то уже из вложенной директории ничего запустить невозможно будет. Но это уже особенность работы sudo.