# Разрешить выполнять с помощью sudo только одну программу

Tags: ubuntu, sudo

Возможно ли разрешить доступ к команде `sudo reboot` обычному юзеру? 
Именно только к ней.

Comment: дубликаты: [один](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/460630/178576), [два](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/552212/178576), [три](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/458365/178576).

Comment: `reboot` прекрасно работает без всяких `sudo`